# How to uninstall Ubuntu 14.10 and perform a fresh install of Linux Mint 17.3

Tags: system-installation, uninstall, mint

I installed Ubuntu 14.10 on top of a (X) Windows 7 PC laptop (No CD ROM) (Windows is gone) thinking that I would like it.  Now I am finding much more in the newer distros- Linux Mint 17.3, Ubuntu 15.10, Lubuntu 15.....04 or 10.. I have a USB key for it somewhere. How do I remove Ubuntu 14.10 and freshly install the Linux Mint 17.3.  I am on a PC but Windows 7 is gone (?).  At least I have been unable to recover it; not that I want to anyway. I am a newbie but I can follow instructions. When I search this item, all seem to still have Windows installed to go back to- not here.  This PC only has Ubuntu 14.10 on it as well as I can tell.

Comment: Close voters: This is not off topic, it is `how to uninstall Ubuntu`, that's on topic, if how to remove ubuntu and put windows on is on topic, then so is this. just because it mentions another distro does not make it off topic.

Comment: AFAIU "How do I remove Ubuntu 14.10 **and freshly install the Linux Mint 17.3**" is still off-topic here...  **:/**  Sorry! **:-|**

Comment: Sorry about the lack of information.  Being really new to Linux Ubuntu does nor help.  Thanks to Eduardo Cola for his having me rethink leaving Ubuntu and I successfully upgraded from 14.10 through 15.04 and am sitting with 15.10 and I like it.  Again sorry for the improper question.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**: before doing anything, have in mind that you can install Cinnamon (Mint's Desktop Environment) in Ubuntu and it will feel pretty much the same.

First download and install Mint into your USB stick. Boot from it.

- First step: check if **everything works**.

You're going to erase Ubuntu and leave your system without any OS until you finish installing Mint. So make sure everything you need (and even what you don't need) works. Check internet connection (wired/wireless), software updates, video/audio streaming, software installation, configuration, etc. After you are absolutely sure that everything works we can go to the next step:

- Backup everything from Ubuntu.

Reboot your computer into Ubuntu. Put all your files in an external drive. Also get a list from your installed apps so you can reinstall them on Mint afterwards. To do it, take a look at this topic: askubuntu.com/questions/17823/how-to-list-all-installed-packages

- Erase Ubuntu.

Boot from your Mint Live USB. Open a terminal and run:

`sudo gparted`

GParted (GNOME Partition Editor) will open up. You can use it to manage your disks/partitions. It should automatically open your main disk; to make sure, click GParted tab>Devices and make sure your main disk is selected. I suppose you have only one HDD/SSD, so it should be `/dev/sda`.

The following are instructions to remove **everything** from your disk. If you want to restore Windows (if it's still there) make sure to NOT delete its partition (it should be NTFS formatted). **No** changes will be made until you click "Apply".

- To remove everything from your disk, right-click every single partition listed in it and click "Delete". After you've deleted everything there will be a single, gray unallocated space. Right-click it and click "New". Make sure it is selected to use the whole disk space and format it to **ext4**. Give it a label, e.g. "Linux Mint". Click "OK". Now click "Apply" (the green check symbol) and the changes **will be written to the disk**. It shouldn't take more than 1 or 2 minutes. Ubuntu (and all the disk content) is now removed.
- Install Linux Mint.

Close GParted and the terminal window. Start Mint's installer. It's pretty much the same as Ubuntu; you should already know how to install it.

- Test if everything works.

If Mint was successfully installed, the installer will ask you to reboot. Do it and test your new system!